# Fatal PHP Error using posting to Twitter using OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a very simple app - for internal purposes - built to post tweets to Twitter automatically.

It was working fine for years (save the need to upgrade to OAuth 2.0 from 1.0) until a few months ago.

It seems to be a problem with linking with OAuth. The error i'm being thrown is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1' not found in /home/content/20/6504820/html/..../twitteroauth.php on line 61
```

Line 61 being straight out of OAuth:

```
$this->sha1_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
```

which at the top of the document requires:

```
require_once('OAuth.php');
```

which in OAuth.php (contained in the same remote directory) contains the method:

```
class OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 extends OAuthSignatureMethod {
```

Again, all of this is straight out of OAuth 2.0 and shouldn't require any edits on my end. (Right?) This leads me to believe it's a server issue?

Quite frankly I don't know how to proceed debugging this issue, might you be able to lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a server issue: had an additional file named OAuth.php buried elsewhere & caused the error.

Solved with thanks to:
[eamann](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/46/eamann)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/multiple-plugins-using-the-same-oauth-class-issues